# Is it bad to call this.setState() from this.setState() in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

For example, I have this kind of code:

```or-tag-here
class Example extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      disabled: false,
      isLoaderOpened: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          disabled={this.state.disabled}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Load</button>
        {this.state.isLoaderOpened && <div>Loading</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }

  onClick = () => this.fetchData(this.state.value);

  onChange = e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value });

  fetchData = value => {
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => this.setState({ disabled: true }, () => showLoader()))
      .then(() => this.handleRequest(this.props.url, value))
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({ data: res.json() }, () => this.hideLoader())
      );
  };

  showLoader = () => this.setState({ isLoaderOpened: true });

  hideLoader = () => this.setState({ isLoaderOpened: false });

  handleRequest = (url, value) => fetch(url + "?value=" + value);
}
```

Is it bad that I call from `setState` function, that also uses `setState`? I want to reuse frequently used methods and for brevity it is comfortable to pass them as callbacks in `setState`.

Comment: why not just set the loader opened in the original setState call?

Comment: You could just set all the parts of state you need right there, rather than invoke a method that does the same.  I would say that having a "hide" and "show" method separately is bad, though.  Use a "toggle" function and pass `true` or `false` as needed.

Comment: @Neal Because It would be strange if in some place I use original setState call and in some place - showLoader/hideLoader methods

Comment: What's strange is invoking `setState` then immediately calling `setState` again within the callback, when the latter does not need access to the results of the first `setState`

Comment: Are you one of those folks that asks a question then never reengages the community? I'll think twice next time I see your name.

Comment: No, I'm still looking for an answer

Comment: @Василий You have two answers that are near identical letting you know the problems with your approach and how to refactor. Take the hint.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not good to call `setState()` twice or more.
In your case, you can try to pass a param to the `hideLoader()` and `showLoader()`
For example:

```
showLoader = (otherState = {}) => this.setState({ ...otherState, isLoaderOpened: true });

hideLoader = (otherState = {}) => this.setState({ ...otherState, isLoaderOpened: false });
```

then you can pass the other state you wanna change into the methods:

```
fetchData = value => {
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => this.setState({ disabled: true }, () => showLoader()))
      .then(() => this.handleRequest(this.props.url, value))
      .then(res =>
          this.hideLoader({ data: res.json() })
    );
};
```